indesign script get/create page by id or label
I iterate thru a table in indesign, getting a room number from that tables first° column:
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var myTables = myDoc.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().getElements(); 
for(var p = 0; p < myTables.length; p++){
   var myTable = myTables[p];
   for (var r = 0; r < myTable.rows.length; r++) {
       var room = myTable.rows[r].cells[1].contents;
       if (isNaN(room))
           continue;
       /* ??? */
   }
}

What I need to do now is: get a page for that room-number or (if not existent) create that page using a certain template. So I guess I can somehow give a page a label or an Id and get the page by that. But how do I...

check whether a page of that ID/Label/WhateverPropertyFits exists?
create that at the end of the document if non existent using a given template?


° I'm not talking about the zeroth column.
